# C#で生成したjsonデータをjavascriptでも使えるようにする方法が知りたい。

Tags: javascript

提示コードですが以下のソースコードの`let json`の`json`文字列を`arr.name` のような形で参照したいのですがなぜ`undefined`と表示されるのでしょうか？参考サイト等を調べましたがやり方は以下ように行うそうです。

###### 提示コードのついて

以下のソースコードは`C# WebView`を用いて`javascript`に`json`データを送り`html`を使って描画するという処理内容です。

`GetSendJsonData_Post(JsonData.Post post)`はそのＣ＃のクラスを`json`データにする処理で`json`コードはその処理した`json`データです。

jsのソースコードはそのjsonの挙動を確認するためのテストコードです。

###### 知りたい事

`C#`で処理した`json`コードを`javascript`側でも使えるようにするために。クラスデータを`json`形式にする方法が知りたいです。

###### 調べたこと

`JsonSerializer.Serialize`でクラスを`json`化
参考サイトを参考にjsonの形に変換してjsonの値を取得

###### 参考サイト

json変換: https://cpoint-lab.co.jp/article/201801/1228/
JSON.stringify(): https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify
Jsonとはなにか？https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

###### デバッグコンソール

```
undefined
Main.js:8 "{ name:sampleName test@mstdn.jp, icon_url:https://media.mstdn.jp, accountPage:https://google.com, content:sampletext }"
Main.js:9 { name:sampleName test@mstdn.jp, icon_url:https://media.mstdn.jp, accountPage:https://google.com, content:sampletext }
```

###### json

```
{"name":"XXXXXXXX","icon_url":"url","accountPage":"url","content":"AAAAA"}
```

###### C# ソースコード

```cs
        /*##################################################################################################################
        * 投稿データのjsonを取得
        ###################################################################################################################*/
        static bool b = false;

        private string GetSendJsonData_Post(JsonData.Post post)
        {
            string name = post.account.display_name + " " + post.account.username + "@" + account.client.instance;
            //Console.WriteLine(name);
            //string icon_url = post.account.avatar;
            string icon_url = "url";
            string accountPage = "url";
            //string accountPage = post.account.url;
            string content = post.content;

            var json = new JsonData.SendData.Post(name,icon_url,accountPage,content);
            

            
            string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(json);
            if( b == false)
            {
                  Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
                //Console.WriteLine(json);

                b = true;
            }
            return jsonString;
        }
```

###### ソースコード

```js
let json = "{ name:sampleName test@mstdn.jp, icon_url:https://media.mstdn.jp, accountPage:https://google.com, content:sampletext }";


let arr = JSON.stringify(json);
var ar = JSON.parse(arr);

console.log(ar[0].name);
console.log(arr);
console.log(ar);
```

Comment: 変数 `json` の内容は JSON ではないので、このデータがある時点より前で何か間違えている気がします。

Comment: C#で生成したjsonをJavaScriptに持ち込む段階で全く別物の文字列になっています。何か取り違えていませんか？

Comment: sayuri 様それはどういう意味でしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問文より

> json
>
> ```
> {"name":"XXXXXXXX","icon_url":"url","accountPage":"url","content":"AAAAA"}
> ```

> ソースコード
>
> ```
> let json = "{ name:sampleName test@mstdn.jp, icon_url:https://media.mstdn.jp, accountPage:https://google.com, content:sampletext }";
> ```

C#で生成したJSONと全く別の文字列になっています。`"`が消えたり空白が追加されたりしています。

> C#で生成したjsonデータをjavascriptでも使えるようにする方法が知りたい。

まずは文字列を正確にコピーする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`undefined
Main.js:12 "{\"name\":\"XXXXXXXX\",\"icon_url\":\"url\",\"accountPage\":\"url\",\"content\":\"AAAAA\"}"`のようにjs側のソースコードを修正したので`ar.name`でundefinedと表示されるのですがこれは何が原因なのでしょうか？

Comment: `var ar = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(ar.name);
`とすることが解決しました。